# TYPO3 - Select / fetch pages accessible to current BE user

Tags: php, database, permissions, typo3, backend

What is the recommended way to make a select / fetch of all the pages, which are accessible for BE user for modifications over all the pagetree (filtering by permissions + filtering by workspace configuration) ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your need, Access module + (optional) [be_acl](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/be_acl) is best way for me to control pagetree access. I never was a fan of Workspaces, so I avoided them years ago, as IMHO they're strongly uncomfortable.

Comment: It could be quite complicated, it's true. And in the case of Access module + be_acl, could You recommend some approach/API to get the bunch of pages, which are accessible to current user ?

Comment: @Fedir But you need to fetch them into your ext ? or just limit the page tree?

Comment: I need to get them all from the database for further manipulations with PHP.